# Column to see Completion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to come up with a way to add an extra column to this result-set that is a bit value of 1/0if the particular owner has all the rows as not null.

[image]

The column would be:

[image]

```
create table #temp
(
    Owner varchar(100),
    Area varchar(100),
    Signed date null 
)

insert into #temp
(
    Owner,
    Area,
    Signed
)
select
    'Owner 1',
    'Area 1',
    NULL
union all
select
    'Owner 1',
    'Area 2',
    NULL
union all
select
    'Owner 1',
    'Area 3',
    '15 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    'Owner 2',
    'Area 1',
    '12 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    'Owner 3',
    'Area 10',
    '5 Nov 2020'
union all
select
    'Owner 3',
    'Area 5',
    '8 Nov 2020'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
    min(case when signed is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by owner) as status
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method :

```
select f1.*, 
isnull((select top 1 0 from temp f2 where f1.Owner=f2.Owner and f2.Signed is null), 1) as status
from temp f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method 2 :

```
select f1.*, 
isnull(f3.result, 1) as status
from temp f1
outer apply
(
    select top 1 0 as Result from temp f2 
    where f1.Owner=f2.Owner and f2.Signed is null
) f3
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method 3 :

```
with temp2 as (
  select  Owner, count(*) NbRow, count(Signed) NbSignedNotNull
  from temp
  group by Owner
 )
select f1.*,
case when f2.NbRow=f2.NbSignedNotNull then 1 else 0 end as Status
from temp f1
inner join temp2 f2 on f1.Owner=f2.Owner
```